# CSS positioning general question about divs and other elements

Tags: css

As seen in the following picture, i make terrible mistakes in CSS, because the task is to edit only CSS and make it look like the goal image.

My attempt:[image: my attempt]

Goal: [image]

Now to my questions: What are the purple things in my attempts and how do i control them? What am i missing? When i move down to mobile size, it looks quite nice...

The tasks code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Agency</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img class="logo" src="./assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <h1>We are a <span>Creative</span> Design Agency</h1>

    <div class="left card"><img class="tile-image" src="./assets/images/beautiful.jpg" alt="hand and flower in water">
      <h2 class="card-title">Beauty</h2>
      <p class="card-text">We strive to create the most beautiful websites for all your needs. Working closely with you
        to
        design and
        develop an amazing website for your business.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right card"><img class="tile-image" src="./assets/images/construction.jpg" alt="metal structure">
      <h2 class="card-title">Construction</h2>
      <p>Built by our team of professional developers, we ensure the most rigourous and modern websites. Built from
        scratch using HTML and CSS. Only the best for you.</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Create. Develop. Design.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

My CSS code:

```
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: #faf9f6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 95vh;
  
}
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 5rem;
}
.logo {
  max-width: 20rem;
}

.logo-container {
max-height: 50px;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: start;
  max-width: max-content;
}

.preview {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.left .tile-image {
  max-height: 260px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.right .tile-image {
  max-height: 260px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6.5rem;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

span {
  color: midnightblue;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  color: midnightblue;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

@media (max-width: 680px){

  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .left .tile-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .right .tile-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .logo {
    max-width: 6rem;
  }

  .card {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: start;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  span {
    color: midnightblue;
  }
  
  footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    color: midnightblue;
  }
}
```

Did try everything with max-width, but as soon as i changed the size it wouldn't fit. The site should be responsive, i only managed to do the mobile size quite OK.

Comment: Can you convert your code into a snippet that recreates the problem or make it reproducible in some other manner?

Comment: Sure! Go to Codepen : codepen.io/CodeRattlesnake/pen/wvNdXGm ; then view full page and zoom out to 80%

Answer (score 0):

try this if still not correct then roll the cards in one div both card and then give properties of width 100% justify content: space between.

.main {display: flex;flex-direction: column;column-gap: 5rem;}

.card {flex: 1;text-align: start;max-width: 100%;}

.tile-image {max-height: 260px;float: left;margin-right: 2rem;margin-bottom: 2rem;}

.left .tile-image,
.right .tile-image {max-width: 100%;}

Comment: This looks much better, the only thing missing is now the two tiles/cards in a row instead of column, got a hint for that? Thanks so far!

Comment: Also the Footer is now at the top right.

Comment: now use the right card and set its value to .left {
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  flex: 1; 
  flex-direction: column;
}


for footer you can set: 

footer {
  margin-top: auto; 
  text-align: center; 
  background-color: #333;  
  color: white;
  padding: 10px; 
}